# Understanding the behaviour of new_root.left in recursive inversions of a binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am working on a binary tree inversion algorithm in Python, and I have come across the following code snippet:

```py
class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return None

        new_root = TreeNode(root.val)
        new_root.left = self.invertTree(root.right)
        new_root.right = self.invertTree(root.left)
        
        return new_root
```

In this code, the `invertTree` method takes a binary tree `root` and recursively inverts it by swapping the left and right subtrees. However, I am having difficulty understanding the behavior of `new_root.left` during the recursive inversions.

Specifically, my question is: Does `new_root.left` change to `new_root.left.left` on each recursion?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide clarity on this matter. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: *"Does `new_root.left` change to `new_root.left.left`"*: what does that mean?

Comment: You have no more interest in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Take this example tree as input:

```
                __5__
               /     \
              2       8
             / \     / \
            1   3   6   9
```

The toplevel execution of the function creates a new node with value 5, but it has no children yet.

Then the node 8 is passed as argument to a second-level recursive call.

> That execution also creates a new node, this time with value 8.
>
> Then the node 9 is passed as argument to a third-level recursive call.
>
> > That execution creates a new node, now with value 9.
> >
> > One more recursive call gets a None as argument, so that call returns immediately with None, and this is assigned to the `left` attribute of new node 9 -- nothing changes. A second recursive call, again with None as argument, has the same result: the new node 9 remains a leaf. This new node is returned to the caller.
>
> That caller has a new node with value 8 and it gets 9 back from its recursive call and assigns it to its `left` attribute:
>
> ```
>    8
>   /
>  9
> ```
>
> A second recursive call is made, this time with node 6 as argument.
>
> > Similar to the case with node 9, this call returns a new node with value 6
>
> The caller, who still has the small 8-9 tree, attaches this 6 to its `right` attribute:
>
> ```
>    8
>   / \
>  9   6
> ```
>
> Then it returns this root node (8) to its caller.

The caller attaches this node to its new node's `left` attribute, so that it now has:

```
     5
    / 
   8
  / \
 9   6
```

Then that top-level execution makes the second recursive call with node 2 as argument. I will not go into the depth of it now, because the recursive process is similar to the one described above. It ends with the following tree that is returned to the caller:

> ```
>    2
>   / \
>  3   1
> ```

The caller attaches this tree to its new node's `right` attribute, so that it now has the final result:

```
     __5__
    /     \ 
   8       2
  / \     / \
 9   6   3   1
```

...which is returned to the main program.